# Component Testing Azure Function without Startup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an isolated V4 Azure Function running in .NET 8 and in the past the way I would component test this would be to have a class that inherits from `Startup` and override a method that configures anything external. The issue with V4 function is that we only have `Program.cs` which has a static method entry which looks something like:

```
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.TryAddSingleton<IRepository, MyDatabaseRepo>();
            services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
            services.TryAddSingleton<IValidator, FooValidator>();

            // Override some DI here??
        })
        .Build();
```

From a testing perspective the way I have tested this is by duplicating the DI and providing the tests with an instance of `IServiceProvider`. For example, in component tests I have this:

```
public static class ServiceProviderBuilder
{
    public static IServiceProvider Create()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IRepository, MyFakeRepo>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IValidator, FooValidator>();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use `Program.cs` but override some of the DI like we were able to before? My understanding is we can't use `FunctionStartup` if its an isolated worker.

Comment: What type of testing are you wanting to do? If you're mocking the dependencies, then it suggests perhaps you're wanting to use Unit Tests. In which case, you would Unit Test your application logic. So just make sure that logic is in a Service/Application layer, not in your Function endpoints, and test that. TL;DR you probably don't want to test the actual host application. I can explain with some code samples, if that would help.

Comment: The approach I was taking was similar to OWIN Test Server where you can utilise the entire system but mock out external I/O dependencies so I wanted a shared startup but substitute I/O components.